# how to display an error message connection?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests

please tell me whether I catch a possible error?

```
import requests
try:
    req = requests.get('http://google.com')
except FileNotFoundError  as exc:
    print('Error open url. ', exc)
```

or FileNotFoundError applies only to files in a file system? in this case, what type of exception I do still use the above code?

Comment: This may help - http://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#FileNotFoundError

Answer (score 2):

[Here](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/api/#exceptions) is a list of exceptions raised by `requests` library. `FileNotFoundError` is not among them.

You should do something like:

```
import requests

try:
    req = requests.get('http://google.com')
except requests.exceptions.HTTPError as exc:
    print('HTTP error', exc)
```

You can catch other exceptions depending on your needs:

```
Python 3.3.2+ (default, Oct  9 2013, 14:50:09) 
>>> import requests
>>> requests.get('googleeeeeeee2323235.com')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
    ...
    "Perhaps you meant http://{0}?".format(url))
requests.exceptions.MissingSchema: Invalid URL 'googleeeeeeee2323235.com': No schema supplied. Perhaps you meant http://googleeeeeeee2323235.com?
>>> requests.get('http://googleeeeeeee2323235.com')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  ...
  File "/usr/lib/python3.3/socket.py", line 417, in create_connection
    for res in getaddrinfo(host, port, 0, SOCK_STREAM):
socket.gaierror: [Errno -2] Name or service not known

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
    ...
    raise MaxRetryError(self, url, e)
requests.packages.urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='googleeeeeeee2323235.com', port=80): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by <class 'socket.gaierror'>: [Errno -2] Name or service not known)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
    ...
    raise ConnectionError(e)
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='googleeeeeeee2323235.com', port=80): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by <class 'socket.gaierror'>: [Errno -2] Name or service not known)
>>>
```

So, in case of an unknown host, you should catch `requests.exceptions.ConnectionError`.

Or you might want catching a base exception for all `requests` exceptions. Consult the docs or the source code to find out what it is.

Comment: The link given by @Ashish open to me but yours doesn't, I tried 3-4 times.

Comment: at req = requests.get('http://googleeeeeeee2323235.com') your script dont output 'HTTP error'

Comment: Even I am having trouble opening the link, but it had opened up quite good earlier. Maybe a temporary issue. Try the cached version - http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:D-hS3NdY8ocJ:docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/api/+&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=in

Comment: @Sergey, I've updated my post. You should first read more about Python exceptions and how to handle them: http://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions